# Remove non-ASCII characters in string from file

Tags: ascii, d

What is the idiomatic way to remove non-ASCII characters from file contents in D?

I tried:

```
auto s = (cast(string) std.file.read(myPath)).filter!( a => a < 128 ).array;
```

which gave me:

```
std.utf.UTFException@C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\utf.d(1109): Invalid UTF-8 sequence (at index 1)
```

and s is dstring ; and:

```
auto s = (cast(string) std.file.read(myPath)).tr("\0-~", "", "cd");
```

which gives me:

```
core.exception.UnicodeException@src\rt\util\utf.d(290): invalid UTF-8 sequence
```

at runtime.

I am trying to parse (with the almost deprecated std.xml module) xml files in a [unsupported encoding](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_encoding.html), but I am ok with removing the offending characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do anything to consider it a string, D tries to treat it as UTF-8. Instead, treat it as a series of bytes, so replace your `cast(string)` with `cast(ubyte[])` and do the filter.

After reading and filtering it, you can /then/ cast it back into a string. So this should do what you need:

```
auto s = cast(string) (cast(ubyte[])(std.file.read(myPath)).filter!( a => a < 128 ).array);
```

Comment: It would be more correct to use std.string.representation rather than casting to `ubyte[]`, because it will retain the correct constness.

Comment: Generally yeah, but std.file.read returns a `void[]` instead of string so in this case you really need to cast it to something to use it anyway.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking that it returned `string`. I should have looked it up.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense indeed. However I could compile what looks to me invalid UTF-8: `char[] a = [ 194, 0 ] ;` ; you know what is specifically treated as invalid in D strings?
There is a small parenthesis mistake in your line of code, I think the cast to ubyte should only be for std.file.read. And good luck for your book! :)

Comment: The check for invalid utf-8 is performed at runtime when it tries to decode the string, so it will let you compile almost any data into it but you won't always be able to use it. (This can be useful because it might be storing some data in between casts, and the compile can't test all possible combinations anyway - imagine appending bytes in two operations, that would confuse the compiler's check anyway). Decoding the string happens whenever you use it with `foreach`, `std.algorithm`, `std.uni`, and other files like `writeln` and `readText` - pretty often!

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the bothering but I forgot to add that I can “print” the above string (got that: ▒) without an exception being thrown. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#Description) the second byte should be greater than 127. Did I miss something?

Comment: writeln might be one of the functions that doesn't decode and just shoves the data straight to the output. Then the console/terminal character set is responsible and isn't necessarily utf-8 (especially on Windows but sometimes on Linux too) or tries to 'fix' it by displaying placeholder characters for the bad bytes.